# What is current in RL-circuit?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, differential

[image]

When t<0
Components in circuit are J<sub>t</sub> = 3 A, R1 = R2 = 2 Ω, R3 = 4 Ω ja L = 10 H

At t=0 switch K will be closed and i need to figure out what i<sub>L</sub>(t) is when t=4

So i tried to figure out i<sub>L</sub>(t) with  differential equation.
First i combined R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> to get R<sub>12</sub>=1Ω 
Then i transformed power supply from current to voltage E<sub>t</sub>=J<sub>t</sub>*R<sub>12</sub>=3A*1Ω =3V
Then i combined R<sub>12</sub> and R<sub>3</sub> to get R<sub>z</sub>=5Ω
Now i can create equation which is 
$$E_t=L*\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}+R_ti(t)          $$
After adding constant i can start solving equation
$$10*\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}+5i_L(t)=3          $$
$$           u(t)=e^{\int5dt}=e^{5t}    $$
$$           e^{5t}* \frac{di_L(t)}{dt}+ e^{5t}*i_L(t)=e^{5t}*3 $$
$$           \frac{di}{dt}(e^{5t}*i_L(t))=3e^{5t} $$
Then for integral in both sides
$$           u=5t $$
$$           \frac{du}{5}=dt $$
$$           e^{5t}*i_L(t)=\frac{3}{5}e^{5t} +C$$
Then divide in both sides
$$           i_L(t)=\frac{3}{5}+ C*e^{-5t}$$
Now i need to figure out what is i<sub>L</sub>(0) so that i can get C, but i don't know how.

Comment: Current through an inductor is continuous. That means \$i_L\$ at \$t=0\$ cannot change instantaneously. Can you solve for the current at \$t=-\infty\$ and \$t=\infty\$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not give full solutions to homeworks, but when t<0, there was a steady state. All transients were dead. Consider the inductor behave as a zero ohm wire until the switch turns. Then the inductor current starts to change gradually towards the new steady state value.

Calculate the initial value from the preceding. Then calculate the new steady state value and let the difference between the initial value and final value die off with time constant L/R where R = 5 ohms. Your time constant is wrong. Your solving method of the differential equation needs repairing.